# ajax post url issue using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

i request a ajax call using jquery

$.ajax{}

on url parameter i hardcoded the path as

```
"/Home/Ajaxpost"
```

its working fine with default, but i hosted in IIS so the project name included in path

like "/Project/Home/Index" so now if the request goes lik "Home/Ajaxpost" fails Action not found.

How can i dynamically set the path for ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
$.ajax('<%=ResolveUrl("~/Home/AjaxPost")%>',{},function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax {
location.host+'/Home/Ajaxpost'
}
```

location.host returns/sets the hostname and port number of the current URL.